# Erro com WCF iniciando como serviço do Windows

Tags: c#, wcf

Estou tentando iniciar um WCF como serviço do Windows, porém ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> O HTTP não pôde registrar a URL http://+:80/. Seu processo não tem direitos de acesso a este namespace (consulte o site http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 para obter detalhes).

Como posso resolver este problema, quando era um executável comum, funcionava perfeitamente, agora como estou colocando ele como serviço do windows, ele fica retornando este erro.

Estou fazendo desta forma para iniciar:

```
ServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Server));
            WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
            binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 999999999;
            ServiceEndpoint point = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServer), binding, url);
            point.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
            host.Open();
            btnSalvar.Log(new string[1] { "CONECTADO" });
```

O problema não é o código, pois como já informei, ele funciona em um exe comum, o erro acontece após colocar como serviço do windows.

Comment: A conta de Logon no serviço é uma conta com permissões? Tentou com uma conta de administrador somente para validar se o serviço inicia?

Comment: Sim a conta é de um administrador ..

Comment: Então deve ser problema de reserva da url+namepace+porta. No link da mensagem tem os comandos para conceder a permissão para o usuário que está executando o serviço. Por exemplo no Windows Server 2008 pra frente ou Windows 7 pra frente, o comando é esse:  `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user` basta colocar o dominínio\login que está usando no serviço

Comment: @RicardoPontual fiz assim, porém continua com o mesmo erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não estou conseguindo achar o link em que achei esta resposta, porém foi desta forma que solucionei o problema:

> Eu estava trabalhando em um serviço WFC de teste hospedado no Windows Service (gerenciado). Então eu adicionei outro endereço base para HTTP. Quando iniciei o serviço novamente, recebi o mesmo erro. Em seguida, alterei a conta de serviço de "Serviço local" para "Sistema local" e isso resolveu o problema.